# getConnection/getRepository typeorm is deprecated

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

i get error for import typeOrm

[image]

anyone know why my typeorm package is deprecated?

[image]

Answer (score 16):

`Connection`, `ConnectionOptions` are deprecated, new names to use are: DataSource and DataSourceOptions. To create the same connection you had before use a new syntax: `new DataSource({ /*...*/ })`.

`createConnection()`, `createConnections()` are deprecated, since Connection is called DataSource now, to create a connection and connect to the database simply do:

**server.ts**

```js
export const appDataSource = new DataSource({
   // ... options
});

const main = async () => {
    console.time('main');
    await appDataSource.initialize();
};

main().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

**user.resolver.ts**

```js
import { appDataSource } from '@server';
import { User } from '@entity/user.entity';

export class UserResolver {
    userRepo = appDataSource.getRepository(User);
}
```

changelog: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: How to get a connection that's configured within a module with TpeOrmModule.forRootAsync({}) ?

Comment: I updated the server.ts example for you.

Answer (score 6):

What is your current `typeorm` version? Because there are several deprecations on typeorm@0.3.0
Here is the change logs file for that
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

*`getConnection()` is deprecated. To have a globally accessible connection, simply export your data source and use it in places you need it*:

```
export const myDataSource = new DataSource({ /*...*/ })
// now you can use myDataSource anywhere in your application
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of using getRepository use this way:

dataSource.getRepository(Entity)

https://typeorm.io/delete-query-builder#soft-delete

Answer (score 0):

it may be that GetConnect is lagged, clicking on the import may suggest which one to replace, or you need to install the library you intend to use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You can do it this way

```
import { TypeormStore } from 'connect-typeorm';
import * as ExpressSession from 'express-session'; 
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Session } from './entities/session.entity';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const sessionRepo = app.get(DataSource).getRepository(Session);
  app.use(
    ExpressSession({
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: true,
      name: process.env.SESSION_NAME,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: { maxAge: Number(process.env.COOKIE_MAX_AGE) },
      store: new TypeormStore().connect(sessionRepo),
    }),
  );

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  await app.listen(Number(process.env.NODE_PORT) || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score -4):

**Try to reinstall package:**

- yarn remove typeorm
- yarn add typeorm

**Can you show more details?**

- this is PosgreSQL?
- show the code base of your solution, may be in [nest docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/sql-typeorm)