# How to replace deprecated getConnectionManager and getManager?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJS application utilizing TypeORM for database access.

TypeORM has deprecated how `getConnection` and `getConnectionManager` can be used. I need direct access to it for dealing with transactions.

How to deal with this nowadays?

The answer at [getConnection/getRepository typeorm is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72535879/getconnection-getrepository-typeorm-is-deprecated) is not helpful and can't be applied on NestJS applications.

My `app.module.ts` looks like this:

```
const connectionOptions: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: config.host,
  port: config.port,
  username: config.user || 'postgres',
   // ...
}
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      cache: true,
      load: [configuration],
    }),

    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ...connectionOptions,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
    }),
```

For handling transactions, I found the following docs:

```
import {getManager} from "typeorm";
await getManager().transaction(async transactionalEntityManager => {

});
```

Unfortunately, `getManager` is deprecated.

In the [TypeORM-Gitbook](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/transactions), I found the following examples:

```
await myDataSource.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
    // execute queries using transactionalEntityManager
})
```

However, it is not clear to me how to achieve this global DataSource-instance and how to inject this one into `app.module.ts` initialization?

In the answer to the question I mentioned at the beginning, they suggest code like:

```
export const appDataSource = new DataSource({
   // ... options
});
```

In the scope of a NestJS application, I can't find a suitable place to inject this.

`package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@golevelup/ts-jest": "^0.3.6",
    "@nestjs/axios": "^3.0.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.3.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^6.3.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.15",
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep it like this and simply inject the global `DataSource`-Object, that NestJS is using behind the scenes, directly in your Services and Modules:

```
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class MyFancyService {
  constructor(
    private dataSource: DataSource
  ) {}
```

Read more here:
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database